# How To rewrite a url with PHP?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Let' say for example one of my members is to **http://www.example.com/members/893674.php**. How do I let them customize there url so it can be for example, **http://www.example.com/myname**

I guess what I want is for my members to have there own customized url. Is there a better way to do this by reorganizing my files.

Comment: That is a good idea as the later url scheme will be search engine friendly. For example when someone search google for 'myname' the users page on your site is more likely to come up because search spiders also scan the url for keywords.

Comment: I didn't notice this before but in the url http://www.example.com/members/893674.php 893674.php is for the user myname right. So is there a file like 893674.php for each user?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a Front Controller, it's a common solution for making custom URLs and is used in all languages, not just PHP. Here's a guide: http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html

Essentially you would create an index.php file that is called for every URL, its job is to parse the URL and determine which code to run base on the URL's contents. So, on your site your URLs would be something like: http://www.example.com/index.php/myname or http://www.example.com/index.php/about-us or http://www.example.com/index.php/contact-us and so on. index.php is called for ALL URLs.

You can remove index.php from the URL using mod_rewrite, see here: http://www.wil-linssen.com/expressionengine-removing-indexphp/

Comment: and When index.php is called for all URLS, it is called single point of entry which simplifies running security checks on you site.
I would also suggest using an MVC Framework, but it might be difficult to port your app to such a Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Add a re-write rule to point everything to index.php. Then inside of your index.php, parse the url and grab myname. Lookup a path to myname in somekinda table and include that path

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

index.php:

```
$myname = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$myname = ltrim($myname, '/'); //strip leading slash if need be.
$realpath = LookupNameToPath($myname);

include($realpath);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new file and change it name to (.htaccess) and put this apache commands (just for example)  into it :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]*)$ members.php?id=$1
```

Comment: I think this answer would be easiest for the OP to implement as it only deals with his point of interest

Comment: You could mention that: http://www.example.com/profile/myname would point to http://www.example.com/members.php?id=myname

Answer (score 1):

You must create a rewrite rule that point from http://www.example.com/myname to something like http://www.example.com/user.php?uname=myname.

In '`.htaccess`':

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$     /user.php?uname=$1
#               SourceURL   TargetURL
```

Then you create a '`user.php`', that load user information from `'uname'` GET variable.

See from your question, you may already have user page based on user id (i.e., '`893674.php`') so you make redirect it there.

But I do not suggest it as redirect will change the URL on the location bar.

Another way (if you already have '`893674.php`') is to include it.

The best way though, is to show the information of the user (or whatever you do with it) right in that page.

For example:

```
<?phg
vat $UName = $_GET['uname'];
var $User  = new User($UName);

$User->showInfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need apache’s `mod_rewrite` for that. with php alone you won’t have any luck.

see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html