# SEO Friendly URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I love the way SO gives link to question
Like this question have the link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002203/seo-friendly-url`
where the question title is `seo-friendly-url`

I'm creating a blog where i want to give the link in the same way SO do, how to do that in PHP ?
Any suggestion is welcome :)

Table Structure

- ID
- Title
- Tags
- Category
- UID

`Added`
*I'm using PHP/APACHE and no framework ! I dont want to use any blog, want to create my own*

Comment: Please do not put **CLOSE VOTE** for fun, please write down the reason !

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is your friend (assuming you use apache as a webserver)

Comment: That close vote suggested to migrate to webmasters.se which in not appropriate since it's a coding thing, not a general SEO question.

Comment: Why not just use WordPress, which does this?

Comment: @ceejayoz i want to keep it very simple and fast ! I'm doing this for learning too.

Comment: another option is to use 404 page where you manually parse all requests and show what you want.

Comment: @ php-coder  i think 404 page is only to show error and something like that :O

Comment: check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481575/how-to-rewrite-a-url-with-php

Comment: What server are you running this on?`If its in apache or IIS you can rewrite from there

Comment: This question *does* belong here. It’s not about SEO but about how to implement something that enables SEO.

Comment: Returned from Webmasters SE as per Gumbo's request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why people are being so deliberately obtuse here...

What you are looking for is `mod_rewrite`, an apache module for URL rewriting.

In your .htaccess file (you might need to make it) put:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog\/([0-9]+)\/.*$ /blog.php?post=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This means when you go to `/blog/10/any-old-bit-of-text/` behind the scenes it is identical to if you visited `/blog.php?post=10`.

The ([0-9]+) bit is called a regular expression (or regex), and matches any number. The `.*` means match anything. The `^` anchors to the start of the query and the `$` anchors to the end. slashes (/) are escaped as `\/`.

Comment: i'll try it and +1 for your help :)

Comment: Your RewriteRule works with blog.php?post=15 but when i view blog.php it redirects to root ! how to stop that ?

Comment: going to blog.php shouldn't be affected by this. Are you sure you don't have any other rewrites in place? You could add RewriteRule ^blog\/$ /blog.php [L] if you want blog/ to go to blog.php as well.

Comment: vIEWING `/blog/10/any-old-bit-of-text/` ALSO DOES NOT WORK :( I placed the .htaceess and blog.php file under a sub directory of root

Comment: It can't be in a sub directory, else it won't be parsed before the request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't write what framework do you user. I describe what you want to do on Symfony framework

**First solution**

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05#chapter_05_route_customizations

1. Change routes to routing engine understand the "Nice urls"
2. Change controller's action which is responsible for searching the right record with your's article

You can enhance the solution by declare sluging function and use it directly in routes

**Second solution**

Use any blogging solution which already supports it - as wrote **ceejayoz**

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP and Apache together. Specifically Apache Forcetype. [This article explains how to use Forcetype](http://www.websitepublisher.net/article/search_engine_friendly_urls/2).

Let's say you have a URL like this: `http://www.example.com/article/seo-friendly-example`

The .htacess file would look like this:

```
<Files article>
  ForceType application/x-httpd-php 
</Files>
```

The PHP would look something like this:

```
<?php
    list(,$slug) = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

The value of `$slug` would be `seo-friendly-example`. This would be a key in your database for that article.

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. Must have been a temporary issue.