# php: Using subfolder path to access posts rather than GET

Tags: php

I'm sorry if there is already a question on this I just couldn't find it since I don't know what it is called.

Basically, I want to be able to access certain posts using their id without using GET. For example, I would like to access a post using `website.com/post/crazy-clickbait-post` instead of something like `website.com/post.php?id=crazy-clickbait-post`. It's just more user-friendly from an advertising perspective.

How would I go about this? I was thinking that maybe there would be a way to use a main post page in the `post` folder called something like `index.php` and then that would parse the url to get the post id but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "the posts"? That expression does not really make any sense. What you are interested in is a value. It is completely irrelevant where you get it from: GET parameters to a URL, post fields in a request or parts of the URL path component.

Comment: If you're using a framework, you'd set up a route. Otherwise you'd utilize rewrite rules in an htaccess file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO Friendly URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002203/seo-friendly-url)

Comment: Seriously, if it's a duplicate, just mark it as a duplicate, I don't need the downvote. I specifically mentioned in my question that there is most likely a duplicate out there, I just couldn't figure out the google query for it. I would have never thought to search SEO friendly url. Thanks to those who were nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want 'SEO friendly' URLs like the following topic:

[How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url)

In your case you need to add this (or create) to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)$ /post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, but gives an introduction into the topic of rewriting and GET parameters. The question is about post requests.

Comment: Will this redirect the user to another url with the GET info, or will the url stay the same? I'd prefer if it stayed the same in case they want to copy it to share it.

Comment: That is a standard rewrite rule which works server internally. No http header for redirection is sent. That means the URL visible in the browser stays the same.

Comment: Perfect, this is the solution to my problem then, thank you Farkie.

Comment: @arkascha I think you are getting incorrectly stuck on the GET / POST thing, I don't think the OP was talking about HTTP Verbs.